# Get entity and count of objects in parent entity

Tags: sql, objective-c, core-data

I have 2 entities, say **'recipe'** and **'collection'**.

They have a n:m relationship. Each recipe is member of possibly multiple collections. And each collection can have a number of different recipes.

One time I have to display all recipes and another time I display all collections of theses recipes (without the multiples).

I have filters for the properties of the recipes. Say, I have 1000 recipes in 10 collections (spread randomly). When I apply a filter, the found number of recipes gets smaller and therefor it is possible there are some recipes missing, which leads to that some recipes of specific collections are completely missing.

**Now I want to display all relational collections, based on the found recipes.** And also **the number of found recipes in these collections**

How do I do it intelligently and efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Sensible TableView framework? I think it's currently the most efficient way to display your Core Data in table views. Saves me tons of time.

Comment: but is it possible to do such a query, like I want?

Comment: yes i believe queries can be done using predicates. You should probably send the admin there, they're usually very helpful.